# Zip in python does not work properly with lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy, zip

Here is what I tried:

```
>>> d
array([ 0.71428573,  0.69230771,  0.69999999], dtype=float32)
>>> f
[('name', 999), ('ddd', 33), ('mm', 112)]
>>> for n1,s1,normal in zip(d,f):
...     print(n1,s1,normal)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Then I tried this:

```
>>> for (name,confidence),normal in zip(d,f):
...     print(name,confidence,normal)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not iterable
```

Where,

```
d = ['Jonathan Walsh','Patrick Walsh','John Welsh']
array = np.array(d)
from pyxdameraulevenshtein import damerau_levenshtein_distance_ndarray, normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance_ndarray
 d = normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance_ndarray('jwalsh', array)
```

Kindly, let me know what i need to do to print the values simultenously? I am using Python2.7.13 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`f` is a nested list, hence to unpack its item to individual variables you need to do:

```
>>> for n1, (s1, normal) in zip(d, f):
...     print(n1, s1, normal)
...
(0.71428573, 'name', 999)
(0.69230771, 'ddd', 33)
(0.69999999, 'mm', 112)
```

This is basically equivalent to:

```
>>> a, (b, c) = [1, (2, 3)]
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
```

While this will fail because `a` can assigned to `1` but now for `b` and `c` there's only one item and Python complains that it needs one more item in the list on RHS or we use the same structure on LHS.

```
>>> a, b, c = [1, (2, 3)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-9-c8a9ecc8f325>", line 1, in <module>
    a, b, c = [1, (2, 3)]
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

From [docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)

> If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object
>   must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets
>   in the target list, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to
>   the corresponding targets.

Answer (score 3):

`zip()` doesn't change the structure of the data it is operating on, it merely puts each element from the sequences together in turn.

```
for f, (s, i) in zip(d, f):
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try list comprehension

```
[[c, a] for c, a in zip(d,f)]
```

Result

```
[[0.71428573, ('name', 999)], [0.69230771, ('ddd', 33)], [0.69999999, ('mm', 112)]]
```